# How to cancel saving data in DB with condition using Loopback's api

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am using Loopback 3. I use method `patchOrCreate` of Loopback for saving data into DB.

Now, I want to check condition to determine to save into DB or not.

I tried to use hook `before save` and set `context` to null. But, it didn't work.

How can I solve this issue with using Loopback api `patchOrCreate` instead of creating my own api?

This is my example code, however, I don't think using hook is an appropriate approach

```
Book.observe('before save', async function checkConditionBeforeSave(ctx) {
    let flag = 0;
    if (// condition 1) {
        flag = 1;
    } else if (// condition 2) {
        flag = 2;
    } else if (// condition 3) {
        flag = 3;
    }

    if (ctx && ctx.isNewInstance && (!flag || flag === 3)) {
        ctx.instance = null;
        ctx = null;
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show handler code?

Comment: You can do this: return Promise.reject()